# what should be the approach to show a progress bar

Tags: angular6

I have a progress bar which works fine. I want to show it whenever the client sends message to server and is awaiting response. The code I have written for this is

```
public getInformation(info:Info):any {

    this.loaderService.show(); //this shows progress bar

    return this.http.post(this.GET_INFO_URL,info,httpOptions)
      .pipe(tap(response => { 
        return response;
      })
      ,catchError(this.handleError)
      ,finalize(()=> this.loaderService.hide())); //hide progress bar

  }
```

The above code works fine but I am not sure if this is the correct design esp. because the response in asynchronous. Is this acceptable approach in Angular that I show a component in one thread but hide it some other? Is there a better, safer way?